# JQGrid fitlering only applied to loaded pages

Tags: jqgrid, filtering, local, paging

Using JQGrid with "local" data, paging and the filterToolbar
The filtering seems to Work but it will only filter loaded pages... so if i have 2 pages, but have only displayed first page, and apply a filter will rows on page 2 not be included...

Comment: Are you doing client-side filtering instead of filtering on the server?

Comment: Yes, it's client side data and filtering.
I have however found the problem myself.
Issue was that my column.name values were pointing to a property which didnt exists on the data objects themselves, this in it self isnt a issue as i use custom formatters for everything.
But when it comes to filtering and sorting, JQGrid apparently dont call the formatter methods to get the values, but relies on the property directly.
So have had to add the actual property to all my data objects with inorder for filtering and sorting to work